# Error in initializing map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

The following code gives error "binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const point' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" .How can I fix it ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct point
{
    float x;
    float y;
public:
    void get() {
        cin >> x >> y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<point, point> m;
    point p1, p2;
    p1.get();
    p2.get();
    m.insert(make_pair(p1,p2));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define `<` operator for `point` because `std::map` uses it for comparison of keys by default.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct point
{
    float x;
    float y;
public:
    // add this function
    bool operator<(const point& p) const {
        // example implementation
        if (x < p.x) return true;
        return x == p.x && y < p.y;
    }
    void get() {
        cin >> x >> y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<point, point> m;
    point p1, p2;
    p1.get();
    p2.get();
    m.insert(make_pair(p1,p2));
}
```

You can also specify a comparator in the third template parameter for `std::map`, but I think defining `<` operator is an easier way.

Comment: why do I get the same error when I use m[p1] = m[p2] instead of m.insert(make_pair(p1,p2)) ?

Comment: @user6275035 For exactly same reason: because operator used is not defined.